# Populate surrogate Datekey based on Date in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, data-warehouse

I have created a table

```
CREATE TABLE myTable(
DateID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
myDate DATE)
```

Then I want to populate the table with data from a staging table using SSIS. The problem is that I don't understand how to generate DateID based on the incoming value from a staging table. For example:
after the staging table inserted 2020-12-12, I want my DateID to become 20201212 and so on.

I tried to google this issue but didn't find anything related to my case. (But I don't deny that I did it badly). How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a persisted computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
     DateID AS (YEAR(myDate) * 10000 + MONTH(myDate) * 100 + DAY(myDate)) PERSISTED PRIMARY KEY,
     myDate DATE
);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dfb3947e145379a514a9aafd8e39729c) is a db<>fiddle.